# The target of 'replace' must be at most one node, found 'text *'

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I'm trying to modify an XML value but keep getting the message

> XQuery [myTable.XMLData.modify()]: The target of 'replace' must be at most one node, found 'text *'

```
<XMLData>
  <Range>60 Kg</Range>
  <Calibration>External Verification</Calibration>
</XMLData>
```

The query I am using for this purpose

```
update o set XMLData.modify('replace value of (/XMLData/Calibration/text()) with "Internal Verification"')
from myTable o
where cast(o.XMLDataas nvarchar(max)) like '%<Range>60 Kg</Range>%'
```

Can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml?view=sql-server-ver15#a-replacing-values-in-an-xml-instance .... pay attention to [1]

Comment: You can change that `where` to `where o.XMLData.exists('//Range[text()="60 Kg"]') = 1` which will perform much better

Answer (score 2):

> The target of 'replace' must be at most one node, found 'text *'

Means the XPath expression might match multiple nodes, but `replace` doesn't allow that.  So you need an expression that matches no more than one node, eg:

```
declare @doc xml = '<XMLData>
  <Range>60 Kg</Range>
  <Calibration>External Verification</Calibration>
</XMLData>'

drop table if exists #t 
select @doc XMLData into #t

update o set XMLData.modify('replace value of (/XMLData/Calibration/text())[1] with "Internal Verification"')
from #t o
where o.XMLData.value('(/XMLData/Range)[1]','varchar(20)') = '60 Kg'

select * from #t
```

Comment: To expand on this, the XQuery processor in SQL Server, unlike most XQuery engines, implements the "static typing" feature of the XQuery specification, which means that your path expression `/XMLData/Calibration/text()` must not only return a single node when evaluated, it must be guaranteed *at compile time* to return a single node.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

Two points to mention:

- It is using a variable **@var** for flexibility.
- It is better to use XQuery XPath predicate instead of `WHERE` clause
  with `LIKE ...`

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<XMLData>
    <Range>60 Kg</Range>
    <Calibration>External Verification</Calibration>
</XMLData>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @var VARCHAR(30) = 'Internal Verification';

UPDATE @tbl
SET xmldata.modify('replace value of (/XMLData[Range/text()="60 Kg"]/Calibration/text())[1]
   with (sql:variable("@var"))' );

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```